# WebBrowser -> Acivity -> WebBrowser, but when the user presses BACK, the browser is closed. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Generally my users use the browser to share a page with my app that analyzes the information received and opens the browser with a new link.

After this, if the user presses the back button, it goes back to the homescreen (my activity is terminated after starting redirection).
I like it when the user presses back, it displayed the page he was before (in the browser).

I understand that instead of redirecting the user I could display the new url in a webview, but I can not work with webview due to other problems.

Below is the code that performs the redirection:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try deleting "finish()"

Comment: `finish()` isn't the issue here. He's basically trying to send an intent to open the *same* browser instance that launched his own app, so that if the user navigates back in the browser, it will go back to the page that launched the app in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use finish(). finish() is to stop/destroy activity. When it will naviagte to browser it will destroy the current activity.

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: When I do this, if I press BACK, my app appears. If I press BACK again, back to the homescreen. What I want is that the user can return to the page (browser tab) he was visiting in the browser BEFORE share the page with my app.